# how to get the unique key that was created adding a child in firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database for my ios project.

I added some fields using `childByAutoId`.

```
[[[_ref child:@"Users"] childByAutoId] setValue:@{@"data": @"my new json data string By aqeel", @"email": @"abc.xyz@email.com"}];
```

Now for some reason I have to search a specific child from database, say an email id. If email id exists I want to get that unique key of that child.

I am doing this

```
[[[[_ref child:@"Users"] queryOrderedByChild: @"email" ] queryEqualToValue:@"abc.xyz@email.com" ] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"%@ Key %@ Value", snapshot.key,snapshot.value);
}];
```

Here in key I get "Users" and in value I get all the entries in`Users` field. But I want to get the key for the child `abc.xyz@email.com`.

Can someone provide me a sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

This means that you will have to [loop over the `snapshot.children`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_data_snapshot.html#aa141d84d6f0575a3095908a1605daf4d).

Alternatively you can listen for a single `.ChildAdded` event and get the child that way:

```
[[[[_ref child:@"Users"] 
    queryOrderedByChild: @"email" ] 
    queryEqualToValue:@"abc.xyz@email.com" ] 
    observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        NSLog(@"%@ Key %@ Value", snapshot.key,snapshot.value);
}];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It does exactly what I need.